# New column in SQL table/view not showing in query results

Tags: sql-server

I added a new column to a view in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. The data area for the modified view displayed the new column. However when I tried to run a query (e.g. SELECT *  FROM uvMyNewView) against that view, it wouldn't display the new column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the [solution](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1427/table-changes-not-automatically-reflected-in-a-sql-server-view/) on the mssqltips website.

```
exec sp_refreshview [uvMyNewView]
go
select * from [uvMyNewView]
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes metadata of view is not updated when we add a column to a table and in view, we use Select * From tablename.

In that condition, we have 2 options either we need to

1. Alter the view script
2. exec sp_refreshview 'ViewName'  Statment to update the MetaData.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but when answering posts you should avoid repeating existing answers.  Your additional information (alter the view script) is not supported with any explanation, and in fact altering a script "just to get it to recompile" is less clear than your second point, which is a direct repeat of the existing answer.  Again - glad to have you contributing, but best to focus your efforts on notably improving the situation.